# What is the proper technique for making fried rice?

Tags: rice, chinese-cuisine

I've tried my hand at making fried rice a few times now. I seem to be getting these things wrong:

- Texture of rice
- Browning of rice

I've been cooking the rice, stir frying some veggies, and an egg in a separate pan. Add rice and egg to veggies, stir fry a couple minutes, eat. How can I improve this?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2509/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47610/67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you let the rice totally cool down before trying to fry it? I always cook the rice the day before and keep it in the fridge overnight.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20935/67